# Difference between regular expression operators in JAPE ( Java Annotation Patterns Engine)

Tags: regex, string, operators, tilde

I would like to know the difference between these pair of regular expressions in Java Annotation Patterns Engine [(JAPE)](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitli1.html#QQ2-12-237).

1. Between `==~` and `=~`
2. Between `!~` and `!=~`

As for the difference between `==` and `=~` I have learnt that `==` is for complete string matching while `=~` is to match a regular expression instead of a string. But when I used `==~` in place of `=~` the result was the same. So kindly explain to me the difference with examples.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific language in mind? Those operators don't even exist, let alone mean the same things, in all languages that support regexes.

Comment: @user2357112: I am learning JAPE (Java Annotation Pattern Engine) that is specially developed pattern matching language for GATE. I have no prior experience with regex. Here is the extract from a tutorial: "There are 3 main ways in which the pattern can be specified: following. 
•  specify a string of text, e.g. {Token.string == "of"} 
•  specify  the  attributes  (and  values)  of  an  annotation.  Several  operators  are 
supported (Equality operators (“==” and “!=”)) 
•  Comparison  operators  (“<”,  “<=”,  “>=”  and  “>”)  and  Regular  expression 
operators (“=~”, “==~”, “!~” and “!=~”) "

Comment: `==~` and `!=~` are for whole-string matching; see http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch8.html#x12-2330008.2.3

Comment: Can you clarify with example @Ruud? I did not get the idea of "whole value match" in the link you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `=~` and `!~`, the pattern can match any substring of the string being tested. In most regex implementations, this is the default behaviour.

`==~` and `!=~` are for whole-string matching. Typically, the same can be achieved by having the pattern start with `^` and end with `$`.

Example:

- `myString =~ "[AB]"` returns true if myString contains at least one A or B
- `myString ==~ "[AB]"` returns true if myString is exactly "A" or "B"
- `myString !~ "[AB]"` returns true if myString contains no A and no B
- `myString !=~ "[AB]"` returns true for any myString that is not exactly "A" and not exactly "B"

See also: http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch8.html#x12-2330008.2.3